# WinForm inside hashtable

Tags: winforms, powershell, hashtable

I can set form elements inside hashtable:

```
$Hash = @{}

$Hash.Main = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Hash.Main.Left = 0
$Hash.Main.Top = 0
...
$Hash.Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Hash.Label.Left = 0
$Hash.Label.Top = 0
...
$Hash.Panel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$Hash.Panel.Left = 0
$Hash.Panel.Top = 0
...
```

How can I write the same thing inside hashtable? I tried to make it as if it could be. And it works. But is this syntax correct?

```
$Hash = @{

   Main = [System.Windows.Forms.Form] @{

      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      ...
   }

   Label = [System.Windows.Forms.Label] @{

      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      ...
   }

   Panel = [System.Windows.Forms.Panel] @{

      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      ...
   }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not take the second code block and _try it_ to see if it works or produces syntax errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this syntax is correct:

### [Creating Objects from Hash Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-5.1#creating-objects-from-hash-tables)

> Beginning in PowerShell 3.0, you can create an object from a hash
>   table of properties and property values.
>
> The syntax is as follows:
>
> ```
> [<class-name>]@{
>   <property-name>=<property-value>
>   <property-name>=<property-value>
>   …
> }
> ```
>
> This method works only for classes that have a **null constructor**,
>   that is, a constructor that has no parameters. *The object properties
>   must be **public** and **settable***.
>
> For more information, see [about_Object_Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_object_creation).

Check the first condition (a constructor that has no parameters):

```
[System.Drawing.Font],        ### does not have empty constructor 
[System.Windows.Forms.Form],
[System.Windows.Forms.Label],
[System.Windows.Forms.Panel] |
    Where-Object { 
        'new' -in ( $_ | 
            Get-Member -MemberType Methods -Static | 
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name ) -and
        $_::new.OverloadDefinitions -match ([regex]::Escape('new()'))
    } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

> ```
> System.Windows.Forms.Form
> System.Windows.Forms.Label
> System.Windows.Forms.Panel
> ```

Check the latter condition (object properties must be public and settable):

```
[System.Windows.Forms.Form],
[System.Windows.Forms.Label],
[System.Windows.Forms.Panel] | 
    ForEach-Object {
        @{ $_.FullName = ( 
            $_.GetProperties('Instance,Public') | Where-Object CanWrite |
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object
           )
        }
    }
```

> ```
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> System.Windows.Forms.Form      {AcceptButton, AccessibleDefaultActionDescription, Acc...
> System.Windows.Forms.Label     {AccessibleDefaultActionDescription, AccessibleDescrip...
> System.Windows.Forms.Panel     {AccessibleDefaultActionDescription, AccessibleDescrip...
> ```

Getting both above code snippets together is a trivial task…